# Can't remove extra line spacing in JTextPane for html content

Tags: java, css, jtextpane

I can't squeeze together the lines in a Java `JTextPane` if I set the content-type to `text/html`. I would like them as close together as they are when the content-type is `text/plain`, the default.

The `line-height`, `top-margin`, ... CSS properties don't seem to help :(.

This is the output of my sample program, that shows that the lines do take more space when a HTML editor handles the rendering:

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Wx4sMDdKKdU/S8cYWIPKhzI/AAAAAAAAAig/4QzFwygmEBs/simpleTextPane.PNG](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_Wx4sMDdKKdU/S8cYWIPKhzI/AAAAAAAAAig/4QzFwygmEBs/simpleTextPane.PNG)

The code that generates the frame is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

public class DemoSimplestGui extends JFrame  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 130;

    private static final String PLAIN_TEXT = "" +
        "This is some <b>plain text</b>\n" +
        "separated by backslash-n characters\n" +
        "There's no empty space between lines\n" +
        "which is exactly what we need.";

    private static final String DIV_BASED_HTML_TEXT = "" +
        "<div>This is some <b>html text</b></div>" +
        "<div>that usses DIV tags.</div>" +
        "<div>There's too much blank space</div>" +
        "<div>and that sucks for my application</div>";

    private static final String PRE_BASED_HTML_TEXT = "" +
        "<pre>This is some <b>html text</b></pre>" +
        "<pre>that usses PRE tags</pre>" +
        "<pre>There's too much blank space grr</pre>" +
        "<pre>and that sucks for my application</pre>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DemoSimplestGui frame = new DemoSimplestGui();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT));
        frame.setSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2));
        frame.init();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        add(createPlainTextPane(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(createDivBasedHtmlTextPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createPreBasedHtmlTextPane(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    private JTextPane createPlainTextPane() {
        final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/plain");
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(textPane.getInputAttributes(), "Courier New");
        textPane.setText(PLAIN_TEXT);
        return textPane;
    }

    private JTextPane createDivBasedHtmlTextPane() {
        final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setEditorKit(configureHtmlEditorKit(textPane));
        textPane.setText(DIV_BASED_HTML_TEXT);
        return textPane;
    }

    private JTextPane createPreBasedHtmlTextPane() {
        final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setEditorKit(configureHtmlEditorKit(textPane));
        textPane.setText(PRE_BASED_HTML_TEXT);
        return textPane;
    }

    private HTMLEditorKit configureHtmlEditorKit(JTextPane textPane) {
        final HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit) textPane.getEditorKit();
        final StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
        css.addRule("body { font-family: monospaced; margin-top: 0; margin-down: 0; line-height: 0; }");
        css.addRule("div, pre { margin-top: 0; margin-down: 0; line-height: 0; }");
        kit.setStyleSheet(css);
        return kit;
    }

}
```

I'd really appreciate some hint :D

Comment: Always try to preview your sites in a browser, as most HTML editor's design views aren't good at rendering what you need.

Comment: This is actually not a preview, the final result of this work is gonna be rendered in a JTextPane. That would be good advice otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This may be platform dependent:

[image: DemoSimplestGui]

Comment: Ouch, thanks for the info, somehow I didn't consider trying in other OSs!

Comment: Even on the same OS, `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` produces a variety of results. `Metal` looks the most homogeneous. I empathize with the "grr". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
StyledDocument doc= textPane.getStyledDocument();
MutableAttributeSet attr= new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(attr, -0.2f); //NOTE: negative value.
```

Looks like you are running windows. What version of JDK/JRE is in use?

Comment: That property is ignored, even if I put 200 as the line spacing they stay the same. Using JDK 1.6.0_13 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! If I use `Courier New` instead of `monospace` for the `font-family`, the line spacing is exactly the same as in the `text-plain` version *under Windows*. Thanks everyone!

Comment: `monospace` is not native of Windows, but I didn't know that they affect the line spacing too.... Strange enough.