# Integrating mxgraph inside JavaFX's fxml file

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jgraphx

I need to make a desktop application that generates a graph on a JavaFX FXML file. I am using mxGraph libary in eclipse to build the graph and Scene Builder to edit the FXML file, but i can't make the graph to show inside the FXML file, it only works when i use JFrame. 
When i run like this:

```
public class mxgraphteste extends JFrame{

public mxgraphteste(){
  mxGraph grafo = new mxGraph();
  Object parent = grafo.getDefaultParent();

  Object v1 = grafo.insertVertex(parent, null, "Brazil", 100, 100, 50, 40);
  Object v2 = grafo.insertVertex(parent, null, "Soccer", 240, 150, 50, 40);
  Object a1 = grafo.insertEdge(parent, null, "loves", v1, v2);

  mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(grafo);
  getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mxgraphteste frame = new mxgraphteste();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setSize(400, 320);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

It works. 
But i need the graph to go inside this:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.TelaPrincipalController">
    <children>
        <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" layoutX="446.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <right>
                <Pane fx:id="paineDireita" prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="126.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="buttonNo" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="179.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selecionarNo" text="Nó" />
                        <Button fx:id="buttonAresta" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="259.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Aresta" />
                    </children>
                </Pane>
            </right>
            <center>
                <Pane fx:id="paineCentro" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" /> **~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ I NEED IT GO INSIDE THIS PANE ~~~~~~~~~~~~**
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I am already using jdk8. I tryed to follow [Oracle's tutorial for Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm#BCGCDEBD) but i couldn't turn the graph into SwingNode. I found solutions using JFXPanel for Swing Applications using JavaFX, but it didn't worked on the opposite. 
Does anyone knows what i did wrong or how can i solve this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32396344/230513).

Comment: Hey Gabriela I'm working in a similar project, write me; yogonza524@gmail.com I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `mxGraph`, so I am just going to assume your code is correct for that part.

To embed a swing component into JavaFX, you need to wrap it in a [`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). As pointed out in the comments, you need to create the swing content on the AWT event dispatch thread. Since the `FXMLLoader` runs on the FX Application Thread, you cannot create your `mxGraph` directly in the FXML file, and will have to do part of the initialization in your controller class.

So you can do the following in FXML:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.TelaPrincipalController">
    <children>
        <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" layoutX="446.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <right>
                <Pane fx:id="paineDireita" prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="126.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <Button fx:id="buttonNo" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="179.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selecionarNo" text="Nó" />
                        <Button fx:id="buttonAresta" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="259.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Aresta" />
                    </children>
                </Pane>
            </right>
            <center>
                <Pane fx:id="paineCentro" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" >
                    <SwingNode fx:id="swingComponentWrapper"/>
                </Pane>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now in your controller you can do:

```
public class TelaPrincipalController {

    @FXML
    private SwingNode swingComponentWrapper ;

    public void initialize() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::createMxGraph);
    }

    private void createMxGraph() {
        mxGraph grafo = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = grafo.getDefaultParent();

        Object v1 = grafo.insertVertex(parent, null, "Brazil", 100, 100, 50, 40);
        Object v2 = grafo.insertVertex(parent, null, "Soccer", 240, 150, 50, 40);
        Object a1 = grafo.insertEdge(parent, null, "loves", v1, v2);

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(grafo);

        swingComponentWrapper.setContent(graphComponent);
    }

    @FXML
    private void selecionarNo() {
        // ...
    }

    // etc etc...
}
```

Note that `SwingNode` only works with *lightweight* components (i.e. those whose painting is managed by Swing); if mxGraph uses heavyweight components this may not work.

Comment: Which version of jgraphx are you using? Can you also post a complete working example to understand better the solution?